# Adding a custom block to the cms home page

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, blocks, template

I want to modify the layout in `page.xml` in `layout` folder for the cms `home` page.

This is the original xml code,

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
<label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
```

This code seems to pull whatever you type in the cms `home` page via the admin area.

So I want to add a custom block inside that block, such as,

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
 <label>Main Content Area</label>
 <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
</block>
```

And it works. But what about adding a custom block that I want to create under `app/design/frontend/MY_LOCAL/template/cms/default/home.phtml` ?

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
 <label>Main Content Area</label>
 <block type="page/html_content" name="content" template="cms/default/home.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Nothing come out. Magento is not pulling that block of template file at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does setting the `type` to `core/template` help?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues here. For one, the `type` or class on your block might be wrong and second, the `name` should be unique.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
 <label>Main Content Area</label>
 <block type="core/template" name="some_random_name" template="cms/default/home.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Comment: No problem, http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates might be a good read for you on the layout. :)

Comment: Updated link: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates